# RAM memory increase and computer crash when compiling python code .py of 330 mb

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have a 16 Gb RAM computer with a 8 CPU inter XEON.
When compiling a 330 mb python code representing an automaton (a class with basically one function but a lot of if else case), The computer crashes. The RAM memory still increase until the computer crashes.

PS: The python code is about 9 000 000 lines of code and is easily opened using a text editor.

Is there a way to split the class before compiling it? Or telling python to do it by part?

```
class FollowCtrl(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 11900
        self.input_vars = ['sys_delta_row', 'env1', 'sys_delta_col']

    def move(self, sys_delta_row, env1, sys_delta_col):
        """Given inputs, take move and return outputs.

        @rtype: dict
        @return: dictionary with keys of the output variable names:
            ['loc']
        """
        output = dict()
        if self.state == 0:
            if (sys_delta_row == 3) and (env1 == 37) and (sys_delta_col == 1):
                self.state = 8022

                output["loc"] = 49
            elif (sys_delta_row == 0) and (env1 == 26) and (sys_delta_col == 2):
                self.state = 870

                output["loc"] = 47
            elif (sys_delta_row == 1) and (env1 == 46) and (sys_delta_col == 3):
                self.state = 10585

                output["loc"] = 68
            elif (sys_delta_row == 1) and (env1 == 46) and (sys_delta_col == 1):
                self.state = 10586

                output["loc"] = 68
            elif (sys_delta_row == 1) and (env1 == 26) and (sys_delta_col == 1):
                self.state = 861

                output["loc"] = 47
            elif (sys_delta_row == 4) and (env1 == 36) and (sys_delta_col == 3):
                self.state = 905

                output["loc"] = 58
            elif (sys_delta_row == 1) and (env1 == 46) and (sys_delta_col == 2):
                self.state = 10591
```

This is the 50 first lines and it is similar for the ~ 80 000 000 other lines

Comment: This automaton should probably be data rather than code at this point, and you should pick a compact data representation (for both the on-disk representation and the in-memory representation). Python was not designed to handle 330 megabyte source code files.

Comment: @user2357112 I just edit my post and give an first line of the code. I don't think I can 'compact' it.

Comment: How have you generated the states in the first place? Consider this, when you're at state 23456876543, there's a good chance you're not going to have to worry about state 56783098545, 23456497808923, 3284505967, and so on. So what you can do is generate your states as you need them.

Comment: Your code looks like a fine case for a database. Maybe even SQLite in-memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a long series of `elif`s is probably not the thing to do here.  Basically it looks like you're mapping a set of 4 integers to a single integer for state and another for `output['loc']`.  You could easily do that with a dictionary, where the keys are a tuple of 4 numbers and the value is the desired integer.  I.e. instead of

```
if self.state == 0:
    if (sys_delta_row == 3) and (env1 == 37) and (sys_delta_col == 1):
        self.state = 8022

        output["loc"] = 49
    elif (sys_delta_row == 0) and (env1 == 26) and (sys_delta_col == 2):
        self.state = 870

        output["loc"] = 47
. . .
```

just do

```
d = {}
d[(0, 3, 37, 1)] = (8022, 49)
d[(0, 0, 26, 2)] = (870, 47)
. . .
```

and so on for all the different states for which you have `elif`s

Once you've created `d` then your function `move` is just

```
def move(self, sys_delta_row, env1, sys_delta_col):
    output = {}
    self.state, output['loc'] = d[(self.state, sys_delta_row, env1, sys_delta_col)]
```

And of course, `d` could be `self.d` if that makes sense for your situation.  I'm not sure why you're creating a dict for `output` when it only seems to hold a single value.

Comment: Okay, so this makes complete sense and is, in a way, an extension of my comment. Basically, you don't need your states in the code, rather keep them in the data. The code should only be concerned with what state it is in currently and act accordingly.

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide Thanks :D I see your point and it makes sense. It's a library called tulip that I used for generating that file. I'll probably modify the generation part to take in consideration your suggestion.Normally it should work.I will confirm that when I will try it. Thanks again

Comment: I should point out, though, that if it still takes too long, you should try what some others have suggested and use some sort of database.  There are some, I believe, that can work just like dicts, so it would require minimal work.  When the memory requirements get too big, it slows down considerably.